# Handling large images

Tags: java, android, memory-mapped-files, filechannel

I am building an app on which I to deal with **extra large images like of 10000X5000 pixels**.The app crashes when I tried to display such images on ImageView.
I can't go for bitmap sampling as I can't change the size of images.

A simple work is to select an image of 10000X5000 pixels and display it in an ImageView.

Currently, I am using simple code for this purpose and app is crashing on it.

```
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String



            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
```

The Exception is of OutOfMemory

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.star.largeiamgesdemo,
>
> PID: 21155
>                                                                                     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 200000012 byte
>   allocation with 4194208 free bytes and 123MB until OOM

Something like `MemoryMapFile` may do the trick but it's for files didn't get anything for images in `FileChannel`

**UPDATE**

I can't scale down images while displaying cause I have to edit them (i.e. user can write something over the images,  or place other images as watermark over them)

Thanks

Comment: Reduce image resolutions and size

Comment: **I can't go for bitmap sampling as I can't change the size of images.**.  You need to scale down your image. What is the format of image? Is it .png, .jpeg or webp.

Comment: As IntelliJ Amiya said but first try to set 'useLargeHeap=true;', this is not recommended method but it can be usefull sometimes.

Comment: @Raghunandan I can't scale down. I have to use some other approach.images can be of any formate

Comment: @Stanojkovic adding useLargeHeap=true; have no affect.

Comment: You need to scale down the image **only** when you are trying to display it in the imageview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say:

> I can't go for bitmap sampling as I can't change the size of images.

so, reduce image size or sample it before show, is not ok. I think below my be a solution.

Because Android's dalvik limit, there is a max heap size you can use. When exceed it, crash happen.

In order to bypass dalvik limit, you can use jni to apply for memory from native heap. You must use `libjpeg` in jni. You can choose show image on SurfaceView, then by `holder.getSurface()` to get a Surface Object, pass it to jni, then use `libjpeg` lib to decode image and show it. Next is some example code, call `showJPG()` function to display large image.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_photoprocessing_activity_SurfaceProcessingActivity_showJPG(
        JNIEnv * env, jobject activity, jobject surface, jstring img) {
    const char * imgChar;
    jboolean * isCopy;
    imgChar = env->GetStringUTFChars(img, 0);
    ANativeWindow_Buffer nwBuffer;

    LOGI("img path : %s  ",imgChar);

    LOGI("ANativeWindow_fromSurface ");
    ANativeWindow * mANativeWindow = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, surface);

    if (mANativeWindow == NULL) {
        LOGE("ANativeWindow_fromSurface error");
        return;
    }

    LOGI("ANativeWindow_lock ");
    if (0 != ANativeWindow_lock(mANativeWindow, &nwBuffer, 0)) {
        LOGE("ANativeWindow_lock error");
        return;
    }

    read_jpeg_file_show(imgChar, nwBuffer);

    if (nwBuffer.format == WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) {
        LOGI("nwBuffer->format == WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 ");
    }

    LOGI("ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost ");
    if (0 != ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(mANativeWindow)) {
        LOGE("ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost error");
        return;
    }

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(img,imgChar);
    ANativeWindow_release(mANativeWindow);
    LOGI("ANativeWindow_release ");
    return;
}

int read_jpeg_file_show(const char *input_filename,
        ANativeWindow_Buffer& nwBuffer) {
    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
    FILE *input_file;
    JSAMPARRAY buffer;
    int row_width;

    unsigned char *buffertmp;

    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);

    if ((input_file = fopen(input_filename, "rb")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", input_filename);
        LOGI("can't open jpg1");
        return -1;
    }
    jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);

    /* Specify data source for decompression */
    jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, input_file);


    /* Read file header, set default decompression parameters */
    (void) jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);


    /* Start decompressor */
    (void) jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);


    row_width = cinfo.output_width * cinfo.output_components;

    buffer = (*cinfo.mem->alloc_sarray)((j_common_ptr) &cinfo, JPOOL_IMAGE,
            row_width, 1);

    buffertmp = (unsigned char *) malloc(row_width);
    memset(buffertmp, 0, row_width);
    LOGI("malloc and memset");

    /* Process data */
    int get8h5 = 248, get8h6 = 252;
    __uint16_t * line = (__uint16_t *) nwBuffer.bits;
    int wheight = 0;

    int scalew = 1, scaleh = 1;

    if (cinfo.output_width > nwBuffer.width) {
        scalew = cinfo.output_width / nwBuffer.width;
    }

    LOGI(" scale of img = %d", scalew);

    for (int i = 0, choosehNum = 0; i < cinfo.output_height; i++) {

        jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, buffer, 1);
        buffertmp = *buffer;

        if (i % scalew == 0 && choosehNum++ < nwBuffer.height) {

            //LOGI("nwBuffer->format == WINDOW_FORMAT_RGB_565");
            for (int j = 0, choosewNum = 0; j < cinfo.output_width; j++) {
                if (j % scalew == 0) {
                    if (nwBuffer.format == WINDOW_FORMAT_RGB_565) {
                        line[choosewNum] = ((__uint16_t ) buffertmp[3 * j + 0]
                                & get8h5) << 8
                                | ((__uint16_t ) (buffertmp[3 * j + 1] & get8h6)
                                        << 3)
                                | ((__uint16_t ) (buffertmp[3 * j + 2] & get8h6)
                                        >> 3);
                        choosewNum++;
                    }
                }

            }
            line = line + nwBuffer.stride;
        }
    }

    (void) jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);
    LOGI("jpeg_finish_decompress !!");

    jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
    LOGI("jpeg_destroy_decompress !!");

    /* Close files, if we opened them */
    fclose(input_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope to help you!

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that you must reduce the image size or your phone can't render the image to show in your `ImageView`. So, You need to scale down the image so that image can be shown in your `ImageView`.

```
int imageScaleWidth = 480; // Change the width
Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString); // imgDecodableString is your image path.
int imageScaleHeigth = (int) ( bitmapImage.getHeight() * (imageScaleWidth  / bitmapImage.getWidth()) );
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage, imageScaleWidth , imageScaleHeigth , true);
imgView.setImageBitmap(scaled);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the Android docs on "Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently"

In particular, you mention you can't for for "bitmap sampling" but notice that Android allows you to read the image file size and then calculate a sampling that will work for the size available. Android will then load only the *sampled* bitmap, which is fine because the screen resolution isn't sufficient to properly display images like this anyway.

Also, be sure to consider the method `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource` for thumbnails.

https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

And last, be sure to use the `largeHeap` `Manifest` attribute, if needed - and look at other memory optimization techniques based on the docs:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html